# json stringify object access code behind asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, cookies

I have set a **json stringify object** to my browser cookie.

```
  json_elements = JSON.stringify(obj);
  $.cookie('cart', json_elements);
```

Now I want this cookie acces from my aspx codebehind. I am trying with

```
 if (Request.Cookies["cart"] != null)
        {
          string co=  Request.Cookies["cart"].Value;
        }
```

But it is not working .... 
please help..

Comment: Are you able to access it using javascript?

Comment: What's the context in which this code is placed? I assumed it was on an ASP.NET page. If it's elsewhere, you may need to do HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies